# Liquidsoap, how to pause?

Tags: playback, icecast, internet-radio, liquidsoap

How do I pause and play from the previous location in Liquidsoap?

I enabled the telnet port with:

`set("server.telnet", true)
set("server.telnet.port", 1234)`

When I connect to the instance I can't find any commands that allows me to pause the current playlist.

The only command I see are `mont.stop` and `mount.start` but they restart the playlist from the start. What I want is for the playlist to start playing again from the same location.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can actually "pause" a stream, since it always has to play something. I solve this problem by creating a special file called "silence.mp3" (without any sound or music, just silence) and playing that file, so when listeners connect to a stream - they don't see any error messages that it's down or not working, but they do not hear anything.